# Rails Newbie: Appending conditions in activerecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a form which is used to filter queries. Some of the form attributes are optional; I'm just wondering how to append them as activerecord conditions if (and only if) they have a set value?

There's a fair few of them, so I'd rather not make a separate query for each pattern of potential values. Any suggestions?

To give a specific example:

```
people = People.paginate(
  :all,
  :include => [:people_postcodes, :people_specialties, :people_states],
  :conditions => ["people_specialties.people_type_id = %s AND (people_postcodes.postcode_id = %s OR people_states.state_id = %s)" % [self.people_type_id, postcodeid.id, stateid]], 
  :page => page, 
  :per_page => 16
)
```

How would I best go about creating an extra condition (say 'nationality') only if the optional 'nationality' attribute is populated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, your conditions are a little insecure.  You're doing basic ruby text substitution, which will let site users inject whatever malicious sql they want.  Instead, format it like this:

```
people = People.paginate(
  :all,
  :include => [:people_postcodes, :people_specialties, :people_states],
  :conditions => ["people_specialties.people_type_id = ? AND (people_postcodes.postcode_id = ? OR people_states.state_id = ?)", self.people_type_id, postcodeid.id, stateid], 
  :page => page, 
  :per_page => 16
)
```

To answer your question, there's no natural way to tack on another condition in Rails 2.x.  I would do this:

```
conditions = ["people_specialties.people_type_id = ? AND (people_postcodes.postcode_id = ? OR people_states.state_id = ?)", self.people_type_id, postcodeid.id, stateid]

if params[:nationality]
  conditions.first += " and nationality = ?"
  conditions.push params[:nationality]
end

people = People.paginate(
  :all,
  :include => [:people_postcodes, :people_specialties, :people_states],
  :conditions => conditions, 
  :page => page, 
  :per_page => 16
)
```

In the example above, I'm assuming nationality is passed in as a parameter, but adjust as needed.  I create the original conditions array, then append the first element (the actual condition string) and add one more element to the end of the array: the nationality value.

I hope this helps!

Comment: +1 for the SQL-injection info. Wish there was a tag(?) on SO called "Dangerous Code" so that newbies (and some oldies) would know that the code is "dangerous"

Comment: Perfect - many thanks. Also: arghh - I thought strings were automatically escaped in SQL; hate that I missed that. I've just learnt rails, mostly through browsing others source code, but this is the second time I've missed a security issue (was compltelety oblivious to attr_accessible for the first month). I've struggled to find a solid list of rails security issues and I'm a little worried I'm missing more. Any suggestions on where to find an overview of common rails security issues?